# Anonymous methods cast as pointers

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, anonymous-methods

can anyone explain why the code below fails?

```
type TIDEThemeObserverFunc = reference to procedure(foo: integer);
var fObserverFuncs: TList<TIDEThemeObserverFunc>

function RegisterEventObserver(aObserverFunc: TIDEThemeObserverFunc): Pointer;
begin
  fObserverFuncs.Add(aObserverFunc);
  Result := @aObserverFunc;

  // line below somehow fails
  assert(fObserverFuncs.IndexOf(TIDEThemeObserverFunc(Result)) <> -1);
end;
```

I assumed anonymous methods can simply be casted and used around via pointers but that seems like a wrong assumption. Also, any resources explaining how the anonymous methods are implemented under the hood would be great. TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use PPointer(@aObserverFunc)^ instead of @aObserverFunc to avoid the failed assert.

@gabr: thanks for ref to my blog, but I should recommend first to read [the Stackoverflow user Barry Kelly](http://blog.barrkel.com/2010/01/using-anonymous-methods-in-method.html) blog as a more competent source of information.

Comment: Reference counting for the list should work, as it is of type `TList<(some method reference type)>`. If reference counting broke with generics, even trivial cases like `TList<string>` would be useless.

Answer (score 4):

Anonymous methods are actually interfaces (more correct - objects implementing an interface).

Read more here: [Anonymous methods in Delphi: the internals](http://sergworks.wordpress.com/2010/01/27/anonimous-methods-in-delphi-the-internals/) (written by Stackoverflow user [Serg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246408/serg)).